# Team Agents and Admins - Apple Developer

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

What is the difference between Team Agents and Admins in Apple Developer's website?
Any rights which are different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the official page: http://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php

The main difference is that team agents can actually enable App IDs and upload apps to either the iOS or Mac AppStore. This is also in my opinion a huge drawback, since in every dev program you only have *one* team agent. If you are a large company, this will not scale very well.

Comment: Is there a way to reassign the agent role to another team member?

Comment: hey @JoeCarroll were you ever able to do that?