# Apple Developer program: Multiple Agents

Tags: iphone-developer-program

Is it possible to have more agents in one Apple Developer program (for companies)?

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out? I am looking for same thing

Comment: @Durgaprasad I cant remember if we did. I know we just shared the credentials between a group of people.

Answer (score 1):

> There can only be one Team Agent.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

But you can have multiple Admins.

See also: [Team Agents and Admins - Apple Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258393/team-agents-and-admins-apple-developer)

Comment: The account holder is the only one who can accept the regular legal agreement updates by Apple and as long as he doesn't, no one else on the team, including admin accounts, can update expired provisioning profiles. This effectively means that when a provisioning profile expires while the account holder is on vacation and unreachable, no one else in the company can submit critical updates to the app store until the account holder is back. How do big corporations with tons of iOS apps handle this?

Comment: @Kaiserludi I happen to be in a company with ~20 iOS devs, ~40 App Store apps. When the team agent is in holiday, I send him a text/skype/call and he'll just visit the appstoreconnect page, review and sign. That's 5 minutes.

Comment: I was thinking of a situation when the account holder is not reachable. i.e. I remember that a collague of mine (luckily not the account holder) once was unreachable for 4 weeks nonstop, because he was on a vacation in a very remote area of the world, where he had no internet and wasn't reachable by phone either.

Comment: Well, and if he gets git by a bus and is in hospital for weeks? I think it's just a really bad idea to prevent companies from setting up redundancy for the account holder account, by having at least two people with that role.

Comment: @Kaiserludi the accident is a fair situation. Well, I guess that there are workarounds by making a phone call to Apple, or by sharing the account password among multiple colleagues.

Comment: Sharing the account password was a perfectly valid workaround for the last 10 years until very recently, when Apple made two-factor auth mandatory. Now one needs not only  the pw, but also access to the trusted device of the account holder, which makes account sharing rather impractical. The phone call to Apple is working.